# C++ wrapper around any collection type using templates

Tags: c++, templates, collections

Extremely new to c++ however have a question regarding templates

Suppose I have a simple template class as defined below:

```
template<typename Collection>
class MySack {
private:
    Collection c;

public:
    typedef typename Collection::value_type value_type;

    void add(const value_type& value) {
        c.push_back(value);
    }
};
```

The aim of the class being to accept any type of collection, and allow a user to insert the correct type of value for the specified `typename Collection`.

The obvious problem is that this is only going to work for types which have a `push_back` method defined, which means it would work with `list` however not with `set`.

I started reading about template specialization to see if that'd be any help, however I don't think this would provide a solution as the type contained within the set would have to be known.

How would this problem be approached in c++?

Comment: You do [detection idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) with [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). But if you really are extremely new to C++, this might be a bit much

Comment: Thanks ill take a look at the links ! And yeah I am, have experience in other languages but isn't really much help here haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I started reading about template specialization to see if that'd be
>   any help, however I don't think this would provide a solution as the
>   type contained within the set would have to be known.

You can partially specialize `MySack` to work with `std::set`.

```
template <class T>
class MySack<std::set<T>> {
    //...
};
```

However, this has the disadvantage that the partial specialization replaces the whole class definition, so you need to define **all** member variables and functions again.

A more flexible approach is to use [policy-based design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design). Here, you add a template parameter that wraps the container-specific operations. You can provide a default for the most common cases, but users can provide their own policy for other cases.

```
template <class C, class V = typename C::value_type>
struct ContainerPolicy
{
    static void push(C& container, const V& value) {
        c.push_back(value);
    }
    static void pop(C& container) {
        c.pop_back();
    }
};

template <class C, class P = ContainerPolicy<C>>
class MySack
{
    Collection c;

public:
    typedef typename Collection::value_type value_type;

    void add(const value_type& value) {
        P::push(c, value);
    }
};
```

In this case, it is easier to provide a partial template specialization for the default policy, because it contains only the functionality related to the specific container that is used. Other logic can still be captured in the `MySack` class template without the need for duplicating code.

Now, you can use `MySack` also with your own or third party containers that do not adhere to the STL style. You simply provide your own policy.

```
struct MyContainer {
    void Add(int value);
    //...
};

struct MyPolicy  {
    static void push(MyContainer& c, int value) {
        c.Add(value);
    }
 };

MySack<MyContainer, MyPolicy> sack;
```

Comment: I like this answer due to its syntactical simplicity and the fact the user can provide their own implementations which means that it is also generic for `user defined` collections as well as those in the standard lib. I also like that you showed how class specialization could be used 
however may not be the most effective solution due to having to redefine the whole class. Thanks!

Comment: I did have one question though, do user defined implementations of `ContainerPolicy` just provide the same methods as `ContainerPolicy` in order to use it as a type?

Comment: Yes, `ContainerPolicy` is just a default in my example. You can use another class that provides the same interface. This is useful when you want to use types from different namespaces, without polluting the other namespace.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::experimental::is_detected` and `if constexpr` to make it work:

```
template<class C, class V>
using has_push_back_impl = decltype(std::declval<C>().push_back(std::declval<V>()));

template<class C, class V>
constexpr bool has_push_back = std::experimental::is_detected_v<has_push_back_impl, C, V>;

template<typename Collection>
class MySack {
private:
    Collection c;

public:
    typedef typename Collection::value_type value_type;

    void add(const value_type& value) {
        if constexpr (has_push_back<Collection, value_type>) {
            std::cout << "push_back.\n";
            c.push_back(value);
        } else {
            std::cout << "insert.\n";
            c.insert(value);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    MySack<std::set<int>> f;
    f.add(23);

    MySack<std::vector<int>> g;
    g.add(23);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can switch to `insert` member function, which has the same syntax for `std::vector`, `std::set`, `std::list`, and other containers:

```
void add(const value_type& value) {
   c.insert(c.end(), value);
}
```

---

In C++11, you might also want to create a version for rvalue arguments:

```
void add(value_type&& value) {
   c.insert(c.end(), std::move(value));
}
```

And, kind-of simulate emplace semantics (not truly in fact):

```
template <typename... Ts>
void emplace(Ts&&... vs) {
   c.insert(c.end(), value_type(std::forward<Ts>(vs)...));
}

...

int main() {
   using value_type = std::pair<int, std::string>;

   MySack<std::vector<value_type>> v;
   v.emplace(1, "first");

   MySack<std::set<value_type>> s;
   s.emplace(2, "second");

   MySack<std::list<value_type>> l;
   l.emplace(3, "third");
}
```

Comment: Note that this will still not work with `std::forward_list`, which requires `push_front` or `insert_after`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use at least C++11, I suggest the creation of a template recursive struct

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct tag : public tag<N-1U>
 { };

template <>
struct tag<0U>
 { };
```

to manage precedence in case a container can support more than one adding functions.

So you can add, in the `private` section of your class, the following template helper functions

```
  template <typename D, typename T>
  auto addHelper (T && t, tag<2> const &)
   -> decltype((void)std::declval<D>().push_back(std::forward<T>(t)))
   { c.push_back(std::forward<T>(t)); }

  template <typename D, typename T>
  auto addHelper (T && t, tag<1> const &)
   -> decltype((void)std::declval<D>().insert(std::forward<T>(t)))
   { c.insert(std::forward<T>(t)); }

  template <typename D, typename T>
  auto addHelper (T && t, tag<0> const &)
   -> decltype((void)std::declval<D>().push_front(std::forward<T>(t)))
   { c.push_front(std::forward<T>(t)); }
```

Observe that the `decltype()` part enable they (through SFINAE) only if the corresponding method (`push_back()`, `insert()` or `push_front()`) is enabled.

Now you can write `add()`, in the `public` section, as follows

```
  template <typename T>
  void add (T && t)
   { addHelper<C>(std::forward<T>(t), tag<2>{}); }
```

The `tag<2>` element make so the `tag<2>` `addHelper()` method is called, if available (if `push_back()` is available for type `C`), otherwise is called the `tag<1>` method (the `insert()` one) if available, otherwise the `tag<0>` method (the `push_front()` one) is available. Otherwise error.

Also observe the `T && t` and `std::forward<T>(t)` part. This way you should select the correct semantic: copy or move.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <forward_list>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>

template <std::size_t N>
struct tag : public tag<N-1U>
 { };

template <>
struct tag<0U>
 { };

template <typename C>
class MySack
 {
   private:
      C c;

      template <typename D, typename T>
      auto addHelper (T && t, tag<2> const &)
       -> decltype((void)std::declval<D>().push_back(std::forward<T>(t)))
       { c.push_back(std::forward<T>(t)); }

      template <typename D, typename T>
      auto addHelper (T && t, tag<1> const &)
       -> decltype((void)std::declval<D>().insert(std::forward<T>(t)))
       { c.insert(std::forward<T>(t)); }

      template <typename D, typename T>
      auto addHelper (T && t, tag<0> const &)
       -> decltype((void)std::declval<D>().push_front(std::forward<T>(t)))
       { c.push_front(std::forward<T>(t)); }

   public:
      template <typename T>
      void add (T && t)
       { addHelper<C>(std::forward<T>(t), tag<2>{}); }
 };

int main ()
 {
   MySack<std::vector<int>>                    ms0;
   MySack<std::deque<int>>                     ms1;
   MySack<std::set<int>>                       ms2;
   MySack<std::multiset<int>>                  ms3;
   MySack<std::unordered_set<int>>             ms4;
   MySack<std::unordered_multiset<int>>        ms5;
   MySack<std::list<int>>                      ms6;
   MySack<std::forward_list<int>>              ms7;

   MySack<std::map<int, long>>                 ms8;
   MySack<std::multimap<int, long>>            ms9;
   MySack<std::unordered_map<int, long>>       msA;
   MySack<std::unordered_multimap<int, long>>  msB;

   ms0.add(0);
   ms1.add(0);
   ms2.add(0);
   ms3.add(0);
   ms4.add(0);
   ms5.add(0);
   ms6.add(0);
   ms7.add(0);

   ms8.add(std::make_pair(0, 0L));
   ms9.add(std::make_pair(0, 0L));
   msA.add(std::make_pair(0, 0L));
   msB.add(std::make_pair(0, 0L));
 }
```